# simple filtering with `grep` , `awk`, `sed` or whatever else that's capable

Tags: parsing, sed, awk, grep

I have a file, each line of which can be described by this grammar:

```
<text> <colon> <fullpath> <comma> <"by"> <text> <colon> <text> <colon> <text> <colon> <text>
```

**Eg.,**

```
needs fixing (Sunday): src/foo/io.c, by Smith : in progress : <... random comment ...>
```

How do I get the `<fullpath>` portion, which lies between the first `<colon>` and the first `<comma>`

(I'm not very inclined to write a program to parse this, though this looks like it could be done easily with javacc. Hoping to use some built-in tools like `sed`, `awk`, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the input will be similar to what you have above:

```
awk '{print $4}' | tr -d ,
```

For the entire file you can just type the file name next to the `awk` command to the command I have above.

Comment: Wouldn't `awk '{print $3}' log | tr -d ,` be better than `cat log | awk '{print $3}'| tr -d m` ? But thanks much!!!

Comment: @user1508893 Yes, you can do that too.  I was not sure if all the input would be the same.  I guess you can tailor that command to suit your needs.

Comment: This is awfully brittle; if the text before the colon can be free-form as long as it doesn't contain a colon, `$4` will be the wrong index in the majority of cases. This is fixable, of course, but the approach will have to be different.

Comment: I would instead use `awk -F: '{sub(/,.*/,"",$2); print $2}'` if you really want to use awk.  Though I think that for the grammar described in the question, a regex or pattern match is more than sufficient.

Comment: @tripleee I agree, it is a little simplistic. My answer doesn't account for much other than a static format.

Answer (score 2):

Or with a regex substitution

```
sed -n 's/^[^:]*:\([^:,]*\),.*/\1/p' file
```

Linux `sed` dialect; if on a different platform, maybe you need an `-E` option and/or take out the backslashes before the round parentheses; or just go with Perl instead;

```
perl -nle 'print $1 if m/:(.*?),/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using bash script to parse this stuff, you don't even need tools like awk or sed.

```
$ text="needs fixing (Sunday): src/foo/io.c, by Smith : in progress : <... comment ...>"
$ text=${text%%,*}
$ text=${text#*: }
$ echo "$text"
src/foo/io.c
```

Read about this on the `bash` man page under [*Parameter Expansion*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Answer (score 1):

with GNU grep:

```
grep -oP '(?<=: ).*?(?=,)'
```

This may find more than one substring if there are subsequent commas in the line.